# Question of proving the limit of $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I know that there are already numerous questions on $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\ln(x)$. However, I am interested in a specific trait when it comes to prove the existence of the limit by the use of rule of L'Hopital.

---

Why is it a dead end if we start off like this:

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}x}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\underset{\text{L'Hopital}}{=}\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}1}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{(-1)}{x\ln(x)^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}(-x)\ln(x)^2=\cdots?
$$

If we start with the right expression then we see that the limit exists and if not we get lost. This seems a bit unsatisfying as it involves a kind of "luck". Maybe there is a deeper sense in this point which I don't see. Or did I simply made a mistake?

---

Hope this question is not too vague. If it is then let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not a matter of the right or wrong expression. If you start with a certain expression, then the application of L'Hopital computes the limit immediately. If you start with another expression, then you get another equivalent limit which you may be able to compute using other methods (or using L'Hopital)

Comment: As in many, many other cases, L'Hospital doesn't hjelp in the particular way you put things. It helps if you write $\;\frac{\log x}{\frac1x}\;$ , though. Things like this one happen lots of times: mathematics don't have to be satisfying in any way for anyone with respect to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality$$\lim_{x\to0}x\log(x)=\frac{\lim_{x\to0}x}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\log x}}$$is false, since the LHS is $0$, whereas the RHS doesn't make sense. And the equality$$\frac{\lim_{x\to0}x}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\log x}}=\frac{\lim_{x\to0}1}{\lim_{x\to0}-\frac1{x\log^2(x)}}$$simply says that a thing that doesn't make sense is equal to another thing which also doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, it is indeed true that if you try to apply L'Hopital's rule to compute the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\frac1{\log x}}$$you get another indeterminate forme. So what? That happens a lot.

Comment: I somehow had the perception that "all roads lead to Rome"... Apparently this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was stated in the other answer.  You could do it this way.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln x}{\frac 1x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac 1x}{- \frac {1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}(-x)=0.$$

Comment: This was not my question.